# How to do Random Array with Strings?

Tags: c++, arrays

I hope this is a very simple question, but how can you random a string within a array

For example, for vaules ill do this

`

```
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
srand ( time(NULL) ); //initialize the random seed


const char arrayNum[4] = {'1', '3', '7', '9'};

int RandIndex = rand() % 4;
int RandIndex_2 = rand() % 4;
int RandIndex_3 = rand() % 4;
int RandIndex_4 = rand() % 4; //generates a random number between 0 and 3

cout << arrayNum[RandIndex] << endl;;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}    `
```

how can i apply this if there is string within the arraynum

I have come across something like this in my serach for an answer though

```
std::string textArray[4] = {"Cake", "Toast", "Butter", "Jelly"};
```

but all I come across is a hex answer which does not change on it's own. so therefore I am going to assume it is probably not even randomized.

Comment: `std::random_shuffle` would be a better choice if you don't want duplicates. As it is, you could very well pick the same one twice.

Comment: @jackson chen : Welcome to SO. You may accept Rapptz answer (by checking the tick mark on the left of the answer), if it solves your problem .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `std::random_shuffle`

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    std::string str = "123456212";
    std::random_shuffle(str.begin(),str.end());
    std::cout << str;
}
```

Possible output: `412536212`

If you're using C++11, you can do the same with C-Style arrays like so:

```
int main() {
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    std::string str[4] = {"Cake", "Toast", "Butter", "Jelly"};
    std::random_shuffle(std::begin(str),std::end(str));
    for(auto& i : str)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Or if you're lacking a C++11 compiler you can do the alternative:

```
int main() {
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    std::string str[4] = {"Cake", "Toast", "Butter", "Jelly"};
    std::random_shuffle(str, str + sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
        std::cout << str[i] << '\n';
}
```